# Change of scene class causes error, Xcode / Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, modal-dialog, action, segue

I am trying to make a small iPad application which features an 'About' page. I have run into an issue when I try to change the class of the about page scene which is displayed modally, as the application crashes when the user tries to access this page. I wish to change its class to "ViewController", which is the same class as my main window (map view), to create actions from buttons on the 'About' page.

Currently I am unable to ctrl+drag to the .Swift file from the About page unless I change its class. Not sure why this is happening :(

The error printed to the console is as follows:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
0 specialised_fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, Uint) -> () –
```

Here is my storyboard with scenes:

[image]

Here is the full ViewController.Swift code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    var location: CLLocation!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // Map variables
    var searchController:UISearchController!
    var annotation:MKAnnotation!
    var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
    var localSearch:MKLocalSearch!
    var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
    var error:NSError!
    var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation!
    var pinAnnotationView:MKPinAnnotationView!

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var showSearchBar: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var moreStuff: UIBarButtonItem!    

    @IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    @IBAction func showSearchBar(sender: UIBarButtonItem!) {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func moreStuff(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showMoreStuff", sender:self)
    }


    @IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    @IBAction func segmentedControl(sender: UISegmentedControl!) {

        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{

            mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
        }
        else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{

            mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite
        }
        else if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{

            mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self

        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

// location delegate methods

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Error code: " + error.localizedDescription)
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar){

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    if self.mapView.annotations.count != 0{
        annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0]
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
    localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
    localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in

        if localSearchResponse == nil{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "No Such Place", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        self.pointAnnotation.title = searchBar.text
        self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude:     localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude)


        self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
    }
}

}
```

I am new to Swift so any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:
This is the error screen presented to me once the app crashes:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used mapKit but I still try.

Looking at your error your getting a nil crash, which indicates one of your properties is nil yet you try to use it.

Having a quick read through your code it seams you haven't initialised

```
var localSearchResponse....
```

Again i don't know the MK API very well so I am not 100 sure what I'm saying is relevant.

Have you checked that all your IBOutlets are properly connected?

On which line do you get the crash when this happens? Do you get the crash before or after changing to the abouts page?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, how would I initialise localSearchResponse? I think that each outlet is correctly connected but I am not 100% sure. It does not tell me which line from the .swift file the error is on, it just shows me what I posted above in my question. It crashes once the user clicks the "About" button on the popover featured above the map view. Ps I updated my question with the error screen presented once the app crashes

Comment: Probably similar to how you init the other properties, something like localSearchResponse = MKLocalSearchResponse(). Is the ShowMoreStuff the about button?

Comment: I think I found the error line, here in the viewDidLoad fund: self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true. showMoreStuff is the button to the popover menu which contains the About page button

Comment: So there is maybe a problem with the mapView IBOutlet

Comment: Maybe, when I remove that line the About page gets displayed but then crashes again. At least I can now see the About page displayed! Do you have any other idea what I could do to fix this issue :(

Comment: Himhh you would need to post some code from the about page view controller. You are again getting a crash but it doesn't tell you which line?. Is it a nil crash as well?

Comment: Yes its another nil crash, this time the error line is in the locationManager func: "self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)"

Comment: Than there is definitely something wrong with the map view property. Check the IBOutlet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105494/discussion-between-james-patterson-and-crashoverride777).